# Explaining Java 8 Collector Interface/Method Signature

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

[`Stream.collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)

Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream using a Collector.
```

[`Collectors.groupingBy​(Function<? super T,​? extends K> classifier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function))

```
public static <T,​K> Collector<T,​?,​Map<K,​List<T>>> groupingBy​(Function<? super T,​? extends K> classifier)

Returns a Collector implementing a "group by" operation on input elements of type T, grouping elements according to a classification function, and returning the results in a Map.
```

Can someone please explain the generics `T`, `K` and `R`? I'm really confused how this kind of method can conform to the signatures above:

```
List<Student> studentList = ....
Map<String, List<Student>> groupByTeachersMap = studentList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getTeachersName));
```

I cannot see how `collect` can return `Map<String, List<Student>>` given the signature above. Can someone explain how to read this signature?

Comment: Do note that the return type of `groupingBy` is `Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>>` where `<T,K>` are derived at method scope. you can now try to correlate it to the argument type expected by the `collect` method of streams. Straight to pick `R => Map<K, List<T>>` now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the following minimal class:

```
class Student {
    String teachersName;

    public String getTeachersName() {
        return teachersName;
    }
}
```

You can relate to your code by matching the return types in and out at each step. Example, the signature for `groupingBy` stands as:

```
// <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>> groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier)
```

and your specific implementation is detailed as:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(new Function<Student, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Student student) {
        return student.getTeachersName();
    }
})
```

which in your case returns

```
Collector<Student, ?, Map<String, List<Student>>>
```

and further, if you look at the signature of the `collect` operation i.e.

```
// <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)
```

thereby in your case returning `R` as in :

```
Map<String, List<Student>>
```

Comment: what is the role of '?' in Collector<Student, ? , Map<>>    or the A?